# Boot camp install from a HDD image

Tags: hard-drive, mac, boot-camp, disk-image

How would one go about imaging an old work computer (old IBM aptiva from 2001ish) with Windows XP and lots of stuff (VPN client with settings etc) to a new iMac, while preserving Mac OSX? I can't simply install XP on the iMac and then reinstall/copy across stuff; it NEEDS to be an image.

Can you even image smaller HDD's and then place them on large ones, or do they have to be the same size?

Recommendations on how I go about this?

Edit: It MUST be boot camp. I don't want to virtualize it from within OsX

Answer (score 0):

If the Mac is new enough, go with a Virtual PC setup of XP, inside OS X (VMWare, VirtualBox, etc.).

That way you can use the image without needing to use Boot Camp.

Comment: It MUST be boot camp. I don't want to virtualize it from within OsX